# Caching Nested Stash List

Tags: matrix, playa, stash

I have a list and nested stash list loading and displaying ok until I try to cache. Once cached they both display fine on first load, but upon reload the nested list disappears.

I'm not clear on how to cache and reload a nested list, could someone please provide an example or modify the code below?

Thanks!

**Not Working (Caching)**

```
{!-- Stash list of homes and communities (in nested list) they belong to. Communities are stored in a playa relation within a matrix field. --}
  {exp:stash:set_list 
    name="home_results_{segment_2}" 
    parse_tags="yes" 
    parse_depth="2" 
    parse_conditionals="yes"
    save="yes"
    refresh="1"
    scope="site"
    replace="no"
  }
    {exp:channel:entries 
      channel="homes"
      dynamic="no" 
      category="1"
      disable="member_data|pagination"
    }
    {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
    {stash:entry_title}{title}{/stash:entry_title}
    {!-- Nested stuff. Stash the communties that this house is in.  --}
     {exp:stash:set_list:nested 
        name="related_entries_{entry_id}" 
        parse_tags="yes"
        save="yes"
        refresh="1"
        scope="site"
        replace="no"
      }
        {elevations} {!-- Matrix field --}
          {stash:incommunity}
              {elevation_community}{title} - {city_province}{/elevation_community} {!-- Playa field --}
        {/stash:incommunity}
        {/elevations}
      {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
  {/exp:stash:set_list}
{!-- End of Home results stash. --}


{!-- Load the nested stash list with communities into content --}
{exp:stash:append name="content"}
    {exp:stash:get_list name="home_results_{segment_2}"}
      <div>
        <strong>{entry_title}</strong><br>
        {!-- Stash get the list of communities the home is built in --}
          {exp:stash:get_list:nested unique="yes" prefix="nested" name="related_entries_{entry_id}"}
           - {incommunity}<br>
         {/exp:stash:get_list:nested} 
      </div>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:append}
```

Comment: Try making the nested stash have a longer refresh then the parent stash. I've a smilar issue and that was Mark's thoughts.

Comment: Good idea, no luck though.

Comment: Try adding replace=yes to the inner tag as well.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the same scope `scope="site"` when getting the lists as when setting, unless you have set the `stash_default_scope` configuration value to 'site'.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark, for some reason I didn't get a notice in my email, so haven't checked back until now. I'll give this a try.